# Use of catch you "in some time"

Tags: word-usage

I had an interesting discussion regarding this.

We (non-native speakers) tend to transliterate the words in English whilst trying to convey our message.

I have often seen here, people use this sentence **a lot**

```
I will get back to you in some time.
or
I will get back to you in sometime.
```

Interestingly I reckon the correct usage should be:

```
I will get back to you momentarily.
I will get back to you soon.
I will get back to you later.
```

However, `in sometime` or `in some time` does sound natural.

Later, sooner and momentarily are indefinite, `in some time` sounds like - today but don't know when!

What is the correct way of conveying this?

Comment: Do people really say "in some time"? I mean, I'd expect "in time". Or of course "in xxx minutes/hours" (substituting a real amount of time). "In some time" sounds far too vague to be useful.

Comment: "I will get back to you sometime" should be fine. *Sometime* means *at some unspecified or unknown time*, not necessarily today. In fact, none of your suggestions imply "today", except *momentarily*, maybe.

Comment: @MrLister True. Which is why the question :) because it translates easily from the native language and sounds... umm.. natural?

Comment: Tell me. What exactly do you wish to convey? And I'll tell you a better phrase.

Comment: "I will get back to you sometime later" or "I will get back to you sometime soon"... Yea, that sounds natural as well. I do not hear `momentarily` often but yes, it seems far too accurate for the usage.

Comment: No, native speakers do not say "in some time", and especially not "in sometime".  At least not in my experience with American (primarily), British, and Australian English.

Comment: @NVZ - What I want to convey is : I will get back to you today - but I want it to sound... as if... they can expect it in few minutes or few hours - but it is happening today. Saying `before end of day` is an option but.. my aim is to psychologically inform them that - I am dedicatedly working on something they need and they can expect it very soon.

Comment: @PellMel True - maybe it is the influence, Haha! but, when it sounds natural people tend to not correct and thus adapt. Umm.. Sorry, does that make sense?

Comment: @MrLister, in speech, one ordinarily distinguishes in part by the brief pause between words in "some time", and in part by context.

Comment: @MrLister There is a thread for it... It shows up as suggestion on my right side box... http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144173/some-time-vs-sometime

Comment: "I will get back to you some time later today [or later this week, etc.]" is the only way I've ever heard anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three suggestions you posted are all viable, but subtly mean different timeframes. **Momentarily** and **soon** are considered less indefinite than **later**.

> I will get back to you momentarily.

Would lead me to expect a response in the next few minutes to an hour.

> I will get back to you soon.

Would mean to me that your response could arrive sometime in the next 24 - 48 hours at the latest, but could also arrive earlier. If I did not receive the response after two days, I would send a follow-up, for instance.

> I will get back to you later.

Has a much less definite expectation without further modification, as in "later today", "later tonight", or "later this week". Without modification, this is probably the most accurate colloquial transliteration of "in some time" which is also equally indefinite, but generally not phraseology that a native speaker would use.

That said

> I will get back to you sometime this evening.

is perfectly acceptable from a native-speaking point of view, so perhaps the modifier is the missing component in those instances.

Answer (score -1):

These two sentences are absolutely acceptable and convey their meaning well, however, they are not commonly used. I expect this is as "sometime" is often used to mean "a specific point in the future, as of yet undetermined" and could cause confusion (since in this case you use it to mean "An indeterminate amount of time"). The latter examples are highly preferable.

**EDIT:** This said, the phrase "I'll get back to you sometime" without the "in" is also perfectly valid (however the reverse argument applies).

Comment: -1 Google Books claims 681 hits for [*get back to you sometime*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22get+back+to+you+sometime%22), but none at all for [*get back to you **in** sometime*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22get+back+to+you+in+sometime%22) (regardless of whether ***some time*** is written as one word or two).

Comment: @fumblefingers yes, and this further backs up my point - these are rarely used

Comment: The way I read it, you're saying OP's ***in*** examples are "absolutely acceptable" (although not common). But I think they're absolutely *unacceptable*.